# Angular + Karma: Testing async functions

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, asynchronous, jasmine, karma-runner

I have an angular service that does some async stuff (based on timers).  One of the things you can do with a timer is define a 'handler' that fires when the timer expires (as in this pseudo-code):

```
flag = false;
timer = new Timer(1000); // ms
timer.handler = function () { flag = true };
```

In this trivial case, the timer would set flag to true after 1 second.  How do I unit test this with Angular/Karma/Jasmine?

From reading the docs, I would have expected this to work:

```
... 
flag = false;
timer = new Timer(1000);
timer.handler = function () { flag = true };
expect(flag).toBe(false);
sleep(2)
expect(flag).toBe(true);
...
```

Rather than being morally upright, that test decided to fail with this:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: sleep
```

After some reading, apparently I can't use angular-scenario with Jasmine.  Ok, I'm cool with that.

**UPDATE** :  *Per the comments, I tested my "working" settimeout method.  It doesn't ever get called.*

<del>So this works:</del>

```
... 
flag = false;
timer = new Timer(1000);
timer.handler = function () { flag = true };
expect(flag).toBe(false);
setTimeout(function () { expect(flag).toBe(true) }, 2000);
...
```

<del>But feels a little weird.</del>

Question:  **Is there a better way?**

*Fun Trivia:  Yep, I know about $timeout.  I have Very Good Reasons(TM) for doing the things I did deep in the code mines, away from the light of day =)*

Comment: why does the standard timeout feel weird?

Comment: if you were to use the $timeout you were able to call $timeout.flush(); with this you may test the pre timer conditions and the post timer conditions. But you do not want it :)

Comment: @rdodev: Well, I don't know if this is why it felt weird before, but I just tested and the expect() inside the timeout doesn't actually get called (I set the time to 10 seconds and reran the test, but it finished almost immediately).

Comment: @Michael: My timer has a method equivalent to flush(), but that's not what I'm trying to test.

Comment: In your last code snippet, when does the Timer() get triggered? At instantiation time?

Comment: did you read this: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/test-asynchronous-methods-using-the-jasmine-runs-and-waitfor-methods.html#fbid=NQb3JN1b2DM ?

Comment: @rdodev:  The timer is trigger on setting the time-- during construction in this case.

Comment: @Michael:  No, but I'll take a look at it.

Comment: @SirRobert so if the timer triggers on instantiation then you are likely assigning the handler after the fact.

Comment: @Michael:  I came up with a workable solution based on the document you linked.  If you want to post an answer, I'll credit it.  Otherwise, I'll give a detailed answer myself.

Comment: please give your detailed answer!

Comment: @rdodev: In this case, the handler was definitely getting set in the right sequence.  The issue (now resolved) was in the test framework quitting before the timers could run down.  I couldn't introduce "blocking" sequences (a la angular-scenario) with Jasmine.  But apparently I can with run()/waitsFor() =)

Comment: BTW, this was by FAR the fastest resolution I've had to an SO question.  Thanks to both of you =)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Jasmine has a way to do async testing using waits() or waitsFor() and runs().  Look [here](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/wiki/Asynchronous-specs).

Code would be something like:

```
... 
flag = false;
timer = new Timer(1000);
timer.handler = function () { flag = true };
expect(flag).toBe(false);
waitsFor( function() {
  return flag;
}, "timer ran");
runs( function() {
  expect(flag).toBe(true);
});
...
```

---

**Note from OP**

This is the right solution, so I marked it as accepted.  I actually ended up implementing a sleep-like method based on this solution, and wanted to share in case it was helpful to others.

In the test file:

```
function loiter(ms) {
  var loiter = true;
  setTimeout(function () {loiter = false}, ms);
  waitsFor( function () {return !loiter}, "Loitered too long", ms + 50); 
}

it("should ...", function () {
  flag = false;
  timer = new Timer(1000);
  timer.handler = function () {flag = true};
  setTimeout(function () {expect(flag).toBe(true)}), 1100);

  loiter(1200);
})
```

I hope this is useful!  I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader to figure out why I did it this way =)

Comment: This is the right answer.  Michael answered first in the comments above, but if he doesn't provide an answer soonishly, I'll accept yours as correct.  Thanks =)

Comment: "I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader to figure out why I did it this way =)"

It would be nice if you'd finish explaining.

Comment: `setTimeout(function () {expect(flag).toBe(true)}), 1100);` should be `setTimeout(function () {expect(flag).toBe(true)}, 1100);` - works great! :-)